# Convert SetPixel coordinates to pixels on console

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I am working in c++, normally the size of console is 25*80 pixels, but I am using setpixel() method to display on the console and it takes much larger values of coordinates, why it is so and how to convert from pixels to setpixel() coordinates.

here is my code for setpixel()

```
   HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
   HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);
   SetPixel(mydc,50,50,RGB(0,255,0));
```

Comment: Are you confusing pixels with cursor positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 25*80 you are referring to is not in pixels, but in characters. If you wish to use `SetPixel` to modify the console window, you first have to get the size of the client area, which can be done with [`GetClientRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The following would draw a red crosshair over the client area of your console window:

```
HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(myconsole, &rect);
for(int i = 0; i < rect.bottom - rect.top; ++i)
    SetPixel(mydc, (rect.right - rect.left) / 2, i, RGB(255, 0, 0));
for(int i = 0; i < rect.right - rect.left; ++i)
    SetPixel(mydc, i, (rect.bottom - rect.top) / 2, RGB(255, 0, 0));
```

Note that the console window can (and will) overwrite your drawings whenever it considers a redraw to be necessary.

Comment: You can also use [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the coordinates of the console display window (i.e. the visible part of the console buffer).  In conjunction with `GetClientRect` you can translate between characters and pixels.  But it's all a bit pointless.

Comment: thank you, "The 25*80 you are referring to is not in pixels, but in characters" this solved the problem

Comment: @arx I have to admit that the main reason I posted an answer was because the idea of using `SetPixel` on a console window intrigued me (in a weird and possibly sexually deviant way) so much that I just *had* to try it.

Answer (score 0):

[ScreenToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) offers a transformation of the screen co-ordinates to the client coordinates. Supply the co-ordinates to ScreenToClient and get the client co-ordinates and draw there.